# MultiVariable Calculus Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show, in general, that $\vert \nabla f \vert^2 =(D_uf)^2 + (D_vf)^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular.

I have tried taking the dot product of the right side, but to no avail.

Comment: I edited your post to $\LaTeX$ify it.  Cheers!

Comment: Robert: Do you know how to answer this proof?

Comment: Are you working on functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 4):

If we are considering 3-D, there are infinite $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to $\vec{u}$. So the statement "$\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are perpendicular" is ambiguous.

By considering 2-D:

$$\mid \vec{\bigtriangledown} f \mid^2=(\bigtriangledown f) ^2 (1)=(\bigtriangledown f) ^2 \cos^2 \theta + (\bigtriangledown f )^2 \sin^2 \theta=(\bigtriangledown f  \cos \theta)^2+(\bigtriangledown f  \cos (90-\theta))^2$$

$$=(\vec{\bigtriangledown} f. \hat{u}  )^2 +
( \vec{\bigtriangledown} f. \hat{v}  )^2= ( D_uf  )^2+(  D_vf  )^2$$